# How to decrypt an encrypted string using openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to develop a php program that encrypts some data which can later be decrypted. However, I am having trouble decrypting the data with PHP using AES-256-CBC algorithm by using the openssl_decrypt() method in PHP. The encryption works but when I try to decrypt it gives me an error:-
*hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, bool given on line 44.*

**My code below:**

```php
<?php

class Encryption{
    
    protected $data, $encryption_type, $key, $iv;

    public function __construct(){
        $mydata = "Is this safe";
        $encryption = $this->secured_encryption($mydata);

        // Decrypting data
        $data_to_decrypt = $encryption;
        $this->decrypt_data($data_to_decrypt);
    }

    public function secured_encryption($data){
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->encryption_type = "AES-256-CBC"; // cipher algorithm
        $this->key = ['6d2d823df2e08c0d3cdf70f148998d49', 'fdb3a18c7b0a322fdb3a18c7b0a320d3'];
        $this->iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->encryption_type));
        $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($this->data, $this->encryption_type, $this->key[0], OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv);
        $final_encryption = hash_hmac('SHA3-512', $encrypted_data, $this->key[1], true);
        $output = base64_encode($this->iv.$final_encryption.$encrypted_data);

        if($output):
            print("Encrypted data: {$output}<br/>");
        else:
            print("Error in encrypting data");
        endif;
    }

    public function decrypt_data($data){
        $this->data = base64_decode($data);
        $this->encryption_type = "AES-256-CBC"; // cipher algorithm
        $this->key = ['6d2d823df2e08c0d3cdf70f148998d49', 'fdb3a18c7b0a322fdb3a18c7b0a320d3'];
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->encryption_type);
        $this->iv = substr($this->data, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($this->data, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
        $decrypt_data = substr($this->data, $ivlen, $sha2len);
        $final_decryption = openssl_decrypt($decrypt_data, $this->encryption_type, $this->key[0], OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('SHA3-512', $decrypt_data, $this->key[1], true);

        if(hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)):
            print($final_decryption);
        else:
            print("Error in decrypting data");
        endif;
    }
}

$encryption = Encryption();

?>
```

Anybody to help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your secured_encryption gives an output of 3 elements ($this->iv.$final_encryption.$encrypted_data) but on decrypt_data you don't split the data and feed the complete (Base64-decoded) data to openssl_decrypt and hash_hmac so you HAVE to get an error when decrypting.

Comment: Don't invent your own crypto scheme. There are well-established modes for authenticated encryption, such as [GCM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode).

Comment: @Peter - I would not say that this is **their** encryption scheme, see [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202). But I agree, that nowadays modes like GCM are more convenient (and modern), as long as they are supported in the respective environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few minor issues in the code:

- There is a return statement missing in the `secured_encryption` method. This is the trigger for the error message (*hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, bool given*), since `$hmac` does not contain a string but is `false`. So at the end of `secured_encryption` you have to add:

  ```php
  return $output;
  ```

  With this, encryption works, but decryption does not work yet.
- When separating the HMac in `decrypt_data` the wrong length is used. SHA3-512 results in a 512 bit, i.e. 64 byte hash, i.e.:

  ```php
  $hmac = substr($this->data, $ivlen, $sha2len = 32);
  ```

  must be replaced by:

  ```php
  $hmac = substr($this->data, $ivlen, $sha2len = 64);
  ```
- When separating the data, start at the position `$ivlen + $sha2len` and consider everything to the end, i.e.:

  ```php
  $decrypt_data = substr($this->data, $ivlen, $sha2len);
  ```

  must be replaced by:

  ```php
  $decrypt_data = substr($this->data, $ivlen + $sha2len);
  ```

With these changes everything works and an output looks e.g. like this:

```
Encrypted data: uTjcPmLK8jTktJ0oy5AqB40d5YFuAbgXMHfNEM6+JOH+DtyYAhckcv3mkLhdOvUqPlriKqYjHO6cpJI3ZdoTSS4lqDr0eH0MMiUpJMSXcan81irvobcdIV+rvaMPPRj7
Is this safe
```

By the way, besides the ciphertext also the IV should be authenticated, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24353). There are also authenticatable operation modes that provide confidentiality as well as authentication, e.g. [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (e.g. `aes-256-gcm`), s. Peter's comment. You can check with [`openssl_get_cipher_methods()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php) which algorithms/modes are available in your environment.

Comment: **I am grateful for your support everyone.** But still having some issues @Topaco, after doing the changes you asked me to do.... I am still getting an error:- *Error in decrypting data*

Comment: @Incrediblecoder - I' ve shared the executable code [here](https://paiza.io/projects/ttOoXzgz7OOr_iEoXbJL1w). Please check if there is a difference to your code.